# Is there a way for to receive comment notifications using disqus without registering?

Tags: css, disqus, comments

I am using Disqus, and I'm trying to find a way for commenters to receive notifications of replies to their comments (or new comments) without registering with disquis. If using native wordpress comments people can check the little box that says "receive notifications" and receive messages when there is a new comment. However, when using disqus people have to register to receive those notifications. Many commenters don't want to register for another service, so people aren't getting notified. Is there any way  to make it easier for people to get notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and talking with disqus, this can not be done. As a free service they want to direct users back to their site to set up an account in order to get features such as comment replies. I've decided to go back to wordpress native comments.